Visualising a mapping
I want to visualise a mapping, say
map = <|0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 0, 5 -> 1, 6 -> 0, 7 -> 1|>

I have tried to do
GraphPlot[KeyValueMap[Function[{k, v}, k -> v], map]]

however the result I get is (expectedly) not what I want. Here's what it gives:

though what I would like is the keys and values should be taken differently. Then, 0 will map to the other 0, 1 would map to the other 1, and so on. Here's a visualisation of what I would like:

though am unsure how it could be done. For context, I am trying to visualise group morphisms. So this is from $\mathrm Z_8$ to $\mathrm Z_2$ by $x\to x\bmod2$.

I believe the easiest way is to simply not use the same name for both "keys" and "values". You can wrap them in some arbitrary wrapper, then remove it in VertexLabels, for example:
map = <|0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 0, 5 -> 1, 6 -> 0, 
  7 -> 1|>

Block[{x, y}, Graph[KeyValueMap[Function[{k, v}, x[k] -> y[v]], map], 
 GraphLayout -> "BipartiteEmbedding", VertexLabels -> {_[i_] :> i}]]


I don't know whether you can easily make the layout automatically be what you want, but you can manually specify the coordinates, for example with:
VertexCoordinates -> Table[x[i] -> {0, -i}, {i, 0, 7}]~Join~
  Table[y[i] -> {2, -i - 3}, {i, 0, 1}]`



Domen, thankyou for the response. That works for me. However, the second graph you have shown is a result of manual tweaking. Maybe I should've put it this way in the question itself, but is it not possible, for example, to "place" the domain elements somewhere together, then draw arrowed lines mapping each one of them to their respective images under the mapping...? Since this is supposed to be a function, so the maps will be diverse

@n11, well, do you always want such bipartite layout, so that you have elements in a row on the left and then elements in a row on the right? If so, you just have to modify slightly the VertexCoordinates to take into account the number of elements, and center them vertically.

that works. I was just afraid with bigger maps, it might get messy. So I was thinking if there is in-built functionality which could better treat such needs... so that the elements will get grouped accordingly. Maybe cluttered together, if linear seems too lengthy.

map = <|0 -> 0, 1 -> 1, 2 -> 0, 3 -> 1, 4 -> 0, 5 -> 1, 6 -> 0, 
   7 -> 1|>;

Graph[S[#[[1]]] \[DirectedEdge] T[#[[2]]] & /@ Normal[map], 
 VertexLabels -> {S[i_] | T[i_] :> Placed[i, Center]}, 
 VertexSize -> .3]


Or if you prefer,
Graph[S[#[[1]]]\[DirectedEdge]T[#[[2]]]&/@Normal[map],VertexLabels->{S[i_]|T[i_]:>Placed[i,Center]},VertexSize-> .3,VertexCoordinates->{S[i_]:>{0,-i},T[i_]:>{4,-2-3i}}]


